# Typescript Decorator, which overrwrites set of property

Tags: javascript, typescript

Im trying to overwrite the "set" of a property with an Decorator

Decortaor:

```
function MaxLength(maxLength: number) {
    return function (target: Object, key: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<string>) {
        var oldSet = descriptor.set;
        descriptor.set = (value) => {
            oldSet.call(this, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Decorated property:

```
private _entry: string = null;
@MaxLength(30)
public get entry(): string { return this._entry }
public set entry(value: string) { this._entry = value }
```

When " oldSet.call(this, value)" gets called, the "_entry"-field stays empty.

Does someone know the correct way to overwrite the "set"-Mehtod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, *don't use an arrow function*.

Currently `this` in `oldSet.call(this, value);` is equal to the global object—not the instance of the class. So instead of assigning to the instance's property it assigns to `window._entry`.

Change the code to instead use a regular function, which will use the function's `this`:

```
descriptor.set = function(value) {
    oldSet.call(this, value);
};
```